# Javascript Class, with one parameter passed to array;

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to invoke a class with the code below:

```
class matchDetails {
        constructor(game, kit, player){
            this.game       = game;   // This remains static;
            this.kit        = color;  // This remains static;
            this.player     = new Array(player);
        }
        addMatchDetails(){
            // return "Coventry";
        }
    }
    
    ab = new matchDetails(23, 'red', 11);
```

On the constructor I want this.player to be an array where I can push additional values but I cannot fathom out how to code it.

Comment: You are setting the array's **length** to 11 without adding an actual element. Do you want the first item of the array to be the value 11 here? Then try `this.player = [player]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is keeping extending your contructor and add lines. You can initialize the array and push the value. See the example below:

```
class matchDetails {
    constructor(game, kit, player){
        this.game       = game;
        this.kit        = kit;
        this.player     = [];
        this.player.push(player)
    }
    addMatchDetails(){
        // return "Coventry";
    }
}

ab = new matchDetails(23, 'red', 'smith');

//pushing additional surnames
ab.player.push('jones');

console.log(ab)
//matchDetails { game: 23, kit: 'red', player: [ 'smith', 'jones' ] }
```

In addition, there is no "color" variable, so I changed it to "kit".

Comment: That is perfect - thank you very much.

Comment: @S.S I am glad to help you. You can upvote my answer to help other developers. Thank you